# Delete-Insert in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql, etl, sql-delete, upsert

I was syncing multiple mongo collection data from multiple servers to single mongo server for one project.As of now it is kind of manual task which I need to run

### The code as below

```
mongoexport -d dbname1 -c collection_name -h mongo1host:27017
      --jsonArray -o collection_name.json


mongoimport --host mongo2host -u user -p password --db dbname 
    --collection collection_name_new < /data/xxx/collection_name.json 
    --jsonArray
```

Then login to the mongo2host

```
db.collection_name.drop();

db.collection_name_new.renameCollection("collection_name")
```

For automating this and avoiding bringing all the collection at one shot we can put filters in mongoexport .But I am not able to find out a way to delete only records present in the staging collection and insert those records to the main collection just like we `DELETE FROM tab1 WHERE id` in `SELECT id FROM staging.tab1` then running
`INSERT INTO tab1 SELECT * FROM staging.tab1` kind of approach in Mongo .If this option is available  this can be easily automated  with out any downtime .Is there anyone tried this thing before or solved this with any other approach ?

Thanks

Comment: You do an upsert with your two commands.  With --mode upsert, mongoimport replaces existing documents in the database that match a document in the import file with the document from the import file. Documents that do not match an existing document in the database are inserted as usual.  Refer to https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#ex-mongoimport-upsert

Comment: @simagix Thanks the above thing is perfectly working